# how to create qr code using float values numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, qr-code

I have a NumPy array that has a shape (1900,). Each element is dtype('float64'). How do I convert this to a QR code?

sample of my array looks like:

```
array([   70000.,       -0.,    60000.,   400000.,   300000.,       -0.,
        -400000., -2100000.,  2150000.,  -700000.,       -0.,        0.,
         470000.,   480000.,   370000.,   420000.,   930000.,        0.,
              0.,        0.,   -20000.,    60000.,   880000.,   880000.,
         -10000.,  -220000., -2290000.,  2420000.,  -520000.,       -0.,
             -0.,   790000.,   560000.,   740000.,   910000.,   930000.,
              0.,   -10000.,   -30000.,   -10000.,    60000.,  1020000.,
         960000.,       -0.,   240000., -1260000.,  2460000.,  -570000.,
             -0.,       -0.,  1290000.,   400000.,   750000.,   860000.,
         930000.,        0.,   -10000.,  -150000.,        0.,    60000.,
        1040000.,  1130000.,   -10000.,   660000., -1140000.,  2350000.,
        -680000.,       -0.,       -0.,   870000.,   200000.,   660000.,
        1100000.,   930000.,        0.,       -0.,  -250000.,    10000.,
          60000.,   710000.,   950000.,   -10000.,   510000.,  -960000.,
        1920000.,  -990000.,       -0.,       -0.,   420000.,   -90000.,
         480000.,  1100000.,   930000.,        0.,    10000.,  -280000.,
          20000.,    60000.,   480000.,   760000.])
```

Comment: which kind of QR code?

Comment: @mozway Normal standart QR code, I did not understand your question.

Comment: 1- there are many types of QR codes, 2- even knowing the type of code, we don't know how you want to encode the data. You must provide a reproducible example of the output

Comment: @AbuMuhandisAlTurki: QR Codes encode bytes. You can't "magically" throw a NumPy array of values at it, this needs to be represented somehow (and for the size of QR, as compact as possible). There are many ways to store your data, as shown here probably very ineffective.  One example based on your data could be "10.000s": `7;0;6;40;30;0;-40;-210;215;....` - you just need to make a reverse function for whatever reads your QR again.   There are surely other ways to do it. You choose.

Comment: @MyICQ i did not understand what you mean. Can you explain it. I have to convert my array to QR code.

Comment: @AbuMuhandisAlTurki basically QR codes are not magical. They are a machine-readable *string*. So you could simply encode as QR `70000,-0,60000,400000,300000...` (and put 1900 elements). BUT! QR codes are limited to a few thousand bytes, and even then they are very large in size. Try yourself online at a QR generator. That's why I suggested you to remove some "zeros", f.ex to divide by 10.000 for each element. This obviously works only if you don't have odd values like `147.194`.  So essentially, you can **not** just "convert arbitrary arrays" of any size to QR.

Comment: [List of QR code capacity by datatype and error correction](https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html).  About 7000 numbers, or 4200 alpha. They switch in a smart way, so you should get to about 5-6000 characters. Given avg 5 characters per element, that's about 1000 elements. You see how you come in short here ? The code by definition can't hold all your data unless it's compacted.